# Fix UIView elements to avoid changing dimensions in "scrollViewDidScroll" function

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, cgaffinetransform, uiscrollviewdelegate

I've created a `UIScrollView` to show it in another `UIViewController` with a header. In my `scrollViewDidScroll()`, I have some code that decreases header's height. But when it performs, all of the elements (Label) in header view changes. Is there any way to keep their dimensions fix?[image]

my `scrollViewDidScroll()` function is here:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        var labelAlpha = 4 * scrollView.contentOffset.y / scrollView.frame.height
        labelAlpha = max(0, labelAlpha)
        labelAlpha = min(1, labelAlpha)
        let parent = self.parent as? ScrollParentViewController
        var viewScale = 1.0 - 4 * scrollView.contentOffset.y / scrollView.frame.height
        viewScale = max(0.5, viewScale)
        parent?.redView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: viewScale)
        parent?.redView.frame.origin.y = 0
        parent?.whiteLabel.alpha = labelAlpha

    }
```

Comment: You mean you need to resize parent view and leave child views with fixed height?

Comment: Yes, in fact I want to transform a view without changing size of its child. @GoCrazy

Comment: How did you create the header for the scrollview? Via storyboard / xib or programmatically?

Comment: With xib @zero3nna

Comment: Has your label a fixed height constraint? I would also sugesst, changing the height of your header via layout constrains.

Comment: @zero3nna Yes. My label has constraint. If I use layout constraint for header, can I perform this action with animation?

Comment: Sure, you can change the constant in UIView.animate() for that.

Comment: @zero3nna I tested this but didn't work for me.

Comment: @zero3nna I found answer. If you want, you can see it below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found my answer. I'll post it for you to use if you need. For this case we shouldn't use transform. We can work with `view.frame.size.height`. You should save view's height size in a variable at the first because its value will change.
so add it to your `HeaderViewController` (In my case its name is `ScrollParentViewController`):

```
var height: CGFloat!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    height = redView.frame.height
}
```

then you can use this variable in your `scrollViewDidScroll()`:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var viewScale = 1.0 - 4 * scrollView.contentOffset.y / scrollView.frame.height
    viewScale = max(0.5, viewScale)
    let parent = self.parent as? ScrollParentViewController
    parent?.redView.frame.size.height = (parent?.height)! * viewScale
}
```

thanks for helps.